# Produce MATLAB variable names based on imported file names

Tags: matlab, variables, rename

I'm importing a number of files from the local directory that end with the following characters and file extension, using

```
files = dir('*_eta.txt');
for file = files'
    load(file.name)
end
```

Which produces the expected result, loading the file into the workspace.

I now wish to transform this one variable (containing two columns, 3003 rows) by splitting out the second column into another variable.

I've already have the code to do this transform, however I would like to name the new variable after the file name, this time omitting the '_eta'.
I have tried using `extractBefore(file.name,'_eta')` within a `who('*_eta')` loop, but find that I can't produce the results I'm after.

I appreciate dynamic variable names are not recommended within MATLAB (or any programming language for that matter) - but I'm surprised that I'm struggling so much to access a variable, cut down the variable name and perform a function.

Additionally, I'd like to keep these as arrays, rather than combining them into cells or structs.

Any help would be gratefully received!

EDIT: Motivation - this is what I'm currently doing:

```
t = (0:0.01:10);

load('MPConst_eta.txt'); load('MVConst_eta.txt');
load('KVPConst_eta.txt'); load('KVVConst_eta.txt');
load('SLSPConst_eta.txt'); load('SLSVConst_eta.txt');
load('MPRamp_eta.txt'); load('MVRamp_eta.txt');
load('KVPRamp_eta.txt'); load('KVVRamp_eta.txt');
load('SLSPRamp_eta.txt'); load('SLSVRamp_eta.txt');

for k = 1:3
    MP_Const(:,k) = MPConst_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    MV_Const(:,k) = MVConst_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    KVP_Const(:,k) = KVPConst_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    KVV_Const(:,k) = KVVConst_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    SLSP_Const(:,k) = SLSPConst_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    SLSV_Const(:,k) = SLSVConst_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    MP_Ramp(:,k) = MPRamp_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    MV_Ramp(:,k) = MVRamp_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    KVP_Ramp(:,k) = KVPRamp_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    KVV_Ramp(:,k) = KVVRamp_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    SLSP_Ramp(:,k) = SLSPRamp_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
    SLSV_Ramp(:,k) = SLSVRamp_eta((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
end
```

As you can see, there's a lot of repetition of the same operation for different files - and there's going to be a LOT more, so wanted to try to do it a smart way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
A = load(file.name);
varname = file.name(1:end-8); % remove _eta.txt
eval([varname,'=A(:,2)']) % save the second column in the variable with name 'varname'
```

It's quite slow and not very elegant, but it will do the trick.

EDIT: Alternative you could use structures and save each file in one field:

```
files = dir('*_eta.txt');
all_data = struct;
for i = 1:numel(files)
  filename = files(i).name;
  dummy = load(filename)
  fieldname = filename(1:end-8); % remove _eta.txt
  for i = 1:3
    % Use the file name to create a field of the structure and save your things in the kth column
    all_data.(fieldname)(:,k) = dummy((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
  end
end
```

Of course, pre-allocating things will make things faster

Comment: @Conquistador: the structure approach is *much* better than `eval`. Please avoid using `eval` if at all possible. Have a look at [Why Variables Should Not Be Named Dynamically (eval)](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval) to understand why.

Comment: Try `for i = 1:numel(files), file = files(i).name; dummy = load(file); fieldname = file(1:end-8); ..., end`

Comment: @jrglez - thank you for that, I'd just managed to work that one out too (hence deleting the comment!). I'm having an issue with your above solution that when writing to the all_data struct, only one (the last) fieldname is appearing?

Comment: @Conquistador: It works fine for me. Can you paste a snippet of that part of the code? Make sure that you are no overwriting the structure in every step of the loop.

Comment: `files = dir('*_eta.txt');
all_data = struct;
for i = numel(files)
  file = files(i);
  dummy = load(file.name);
  fieldName = file.name(1:end-8);
  for k = 1:3
    all_data.(fieldName)(:,k) = dummy((k-1)*length(t)+1:k*length(t),2);
  end
end`

This is the loop, pretty much as you produced in your answer above - curious that it's producing a 1x1 struct for me, and working for you

Comment: @Conquistador, you are doing only the last step of the loop (`for i = numel(files)`), but it should be `for i = 1:numel(files)`